# If statement in BizTalk expression shape

Tags: if-statement, expression, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I've read conflicting things about this so before I start the work, can anyone confirm or otherwise if `If` statements will work inside BizTalk expression shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do work, I've used them in a Biztalk 2006r2 expression shape (IF() {} else {} etc.).

You can't control the flow through the orchestration with them though. You will want to use a decide shape for that (which acts like an IF statement).

I tend to use IF statements in expressions to set a variable e.g. :

```
 if (somecondition)
 {
   somevariable = true;
 }
 else
 {
   somevariable = false;
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what Im using it for. I have decide shape anyway, but when the flow goes down a particular branch I have an expression where I want to set variables depending on a condition.

Comment: certainly do-able.  Also might be a bit overkill for your question but you know you can call a method on an assembly from the expressions too?  So if you have a very complicated method that was pain to program into an expression you can just make a helper DLL.  Reference it by adding a vairable and set the type to your .Net Class, remember to make your class Serializable though!  There is an example here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27288/Call-a-custom-NET-component-from-BizTalk-2006

Comment: We do have a lot of helper classes, but for this particular thing its as simple as setting a few variables so the expression was my preferred option, Id just never seen (in here) conditions in an expression.  thanks again